# how to run "sudo passwd username" noninteractively

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, debian, passwd

In a shell script with sudo privileges, I'm trying to change another users password.

I tried `sudo passwd username` but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Are you root user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `chpasswd` command. You can try something like this:

```
echo "username:password" | sudo chpasswd
```

I used it many times. It worked for me.